# White horse in season 2 of Zorro (1957)

Tags: plot-explanation, zorro

In season 1 of [Zorro (1957)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050079/), Zorro's horse, Tornado was black, but in the first half of season 2 it was white, and the second half the season it was black. Was this oversight, or two different horses? Maybe I just wasn't paying enough attention to plot details. If it was two different horses what was the name of the second horse and what happened to Tornado?

Comment: Thank you for the answers...didn't pay attention to WHERE Diego was when riding Phantam as Zorro. I remember the way he GOT The horse, but didn't pay attention to the location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Diego is in Los Angeles, he rides Tornado (the black horse) when he becomes Zorro. When Diego traveled to Monterey, he did not take Tornado with him, and a new horse named Phantom (the white horse) was introduced. Phantom was given to Zorro by a dying soldier and it is not revealed in the series where Phantom hides out while Diego is in Monterey — or what happened to him after Diego returned to Los Angeles.

---

**Sources:**

- [www.imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050079/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)
- [www.billcotter.com](http://www.billcotter.com/zorro/faq.htm#horse)